# Porqué una función valida un número no declarado de argumentos?

Tags: javascript

1. La función doTask tiene dos parámetros, iteraciones y callback
2. Esta función es llamada dos veces (COMENTADAS)
3. Porqué la función funciona cuando sólo recibe un argumento???

La salida en caso de que salga un 6 --> 1 2 3... 6 Se ha sacado un 6

En caso de que no salga un 6--> 123...[1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 6, 7]

Supongo que tendría más sentido y también funciona si en la primera llamada el callback

tuviese dos argumentos (true y el objeto result)

```js
function doTask (iteraciones, callback){

     const numbers=[];
     for(let i=0; i<iteraciones; i++){
        const number=1 +parseInt(Math.random()*6);
        numbers.push(number);
        console.info(number);
        if(number==6){
            callback({ error: true, message:" 6"}); //LLAMADA-->AQUÍ SÓLO HAY UN 
                                            //ARGUMENTO, CUANDO LO LÓGICO SERÍA UN 
                                            // TRUE ,{error:true, message:" 6"}
            return;
        }
     }
    //si termina el bucle y no ha salido un 6
     return callback(null, {error: false, value: numbers});//LLAMADA--> AQUÍ SI HAY 2 
                                                           //ARGUMENTOS,NULL(ENTIENDO QUE 
                                                           //FUNCIONA COMO FALSE) Y EL 
                                                           //OBJETO
    }

     doTask(10, function(err, result){
        if(err){
       
          console.error("Se ha sacado un ", err.message); //AQUÍ TENDRÍA SENTIDO  
              //result.message
          return;
        }
        else {
          console.log("Tiradas correctas: ", result.value);
        }
    
     });
```

Comment: funciona? no hay errores en la consola?  habria que tener un ejemplo completo para probar todo...

Comment: @gbianchi un ctrl+c , ctrl+v y node dados.js. Funcionar, funciona (aunque soy profano, esto es seguramente me equivoco en algo 100%)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es una convención. [Los callback reciben un eventual error como primer parámetro y un eventual resultado como segundo ídem](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/errors/what-are-the-error-conventions/).

Aunque en rigor tú podrías hacerlo como planteas en tu pregunta:

```
// si sale 6
callback(true, {error:true, message:'6'})
```

Y luego verificar la salida como:

```
doTask(10, (err, result)=>{
   if(err) {
     console.error(result.message);
   }
   console.log({tiradasCorrectas: result.value});
});
```

Estarías buscando problemas. La estructura de result será incierta siendo que dependía de tí conocerla de antemano. Más incertidumbre implica más complejidad en el código para controlarla.

La convención va más allá, y a la luz de ésta tu implementación tampoco cumple:  `err` debiese ser un objeto de tipo `Error` y no un objeto plano
(ni menos un `boolean`)

```
  callback(new Error('Usted ha sacado 6'))
```

Si bien tu callback, como todos, espera un segundo parámetro, puedes invocarla con un solo argumento. Javascript nunca ha tenido problemas con esto. Ese camino lleva a que `result` sea `undefined` y eso no es ningún problema a menos que quieras tratarlo como objeto o función. Por ejemplo si pasaras por alto que el callback devolvió un error:

```
 doTask(10, function(err, result) {
    console.log(result); // undefined
    console.log(result+1); // NaN
    console.log('Result es:'+result); // Result es: undefined
    console.log(result.value) // Cannot read property 'value' of undefined 
 })
```

---

#### Para qué seguir la convención?

Pensemos que dentro del scope donde ocurre tu procedimiento tienes otra lógica que obtiene sus resultados de una base de datos, un llamado a un API externa, etc. Esas librerías usarían la convención y tendrías que manejar la salida del callback de una manera, y tu función de otra. Caso a caso. Si te ajustas a la convención, en cambio, podrás tratar los errores en forma homogénea, incluso con un handler común:

```
const resultCallback = (err, result) => {
  if(err) {
     console.error(err.message);
  }
  console.log(result);
}

doTask(10, resultCallback);
callApi({user:'Javi'}, resultCallback);
Connection.getComments({user_id: 1}, resultCallback);
```

Y mejor todavía, mandar el error aguas arriba para ser manejado por un handler superior

```
const resultCallback = (err, result) => {
  if(err) {
    throw err  // algo que no sea un error no debiera ser arrojado
  }
  console.log(result);
}
```

También podrías promisificar tu función usando

```
const util = require('util');

function doTask(...) { ... }

const doTaskAsync = util.promisify(doTask);

doTaskAsync(10)
   .then(result => console.log(result))
   .catch(err => console.error(err.message));
```

Casi todas las librerías hoy soportan la invocación con callback como usando promesas, indistintamente, así que podrías encadenar las llamadas del penúltimo ejemplo para no introducir una *race condition*

```
doTaskAsync(10)
   .then(result => {
      console.log(result)
      return callApi({user:'Javi'})
   })
   .then(apiResult => {
      console.log(apiResult)
      return Connection.getComments({user_id:1})
   })
   .then(comments => {
      console.log(comments)
      return comments
   })
   .catch(err => console.error(err.message));
```

Si tu callback usa otra cosa como primer parámetro que no sea un error, lo de arriba no manejará grácilmente una tirada que saque 6. Node te reclamará: *"Promise rejected with a non error"*

Comment: Gracias. La verdad, me ha ayudado mucho a empezar a entender js